# How to handle large number of arguments to python function?

Tags: python

I have a function that have large number of arguments passed to it.

Dummy code:

**Definition**

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, arg2, arg4,
        arg4, arg6, arg7, arg8):
    #some operation on args
```

**call**

```
foo(arg1, arg2, arg2, arg4,
    arg4, arg6, arg7, arg8)
```

One solution could be

**Definition**

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    arg1 = kwargs['arg1']
```

**call**

```
kwargs = {'arg1':arg1,'arg2':arg2, 'arg3':arg3, 'arg4':arg4, 
          'arg5':arg5, 'arg6':arg6, 'arg7':arg7, 'arg8':arg8}
foo(**kwargs)
```

I am not sure about this being the best choice available in this situation.

Can someone suggest the pythonic approach to this problem of large number of arguments to a function?

Comment: The pythonic approach is not to have such a large number of arguments to a function.

Comment: just pass all the arguments in a list (like argv does)

Comment: @wim I agree on this, but at times you work on code thats already written and you cannot refactor it easily. Looking for a somewhat clean solution. Although I plan to do it.

Comment: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145055/are-there-guidelines-on-how-many-parameters-a-function-should-accept - this is essentially a dupe (at least answer to this question). You either split it to multiple functions or introduce some form of structure that holds multiple related parameters and is passed as single argument. As always in case like this, you need a context and business knowledge about a problem. You can't solve that when knowing only `foo(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8)` - it gives no more knowledge that `8`.

Comment: Looks like passing the parameters in a list is not a good idea (at least according to the troll that downvoted the answer). So I'm happily deleting it. Hope that the troll has a better solution to the problem and will post it.

Comment: In your second solution, you don't need to create a list. You can just pass them as named parameters.